# Setting the lifetime of a session within Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

How would I set the PHPSESSID for Laravel 5 to have a lifetime of one day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `'lifetime' => 1440` at `config/session.php`.

Comment: I have set this parameter but PHPSESSID don't change after login

Comment: The question is setting the lifetime of a session and not regenerating it. I don't know if the Auth service from Laravel relies in the PHPSESSID.